# How do I prevent the Cloud9 IDE (ACE) from automatically inserting a new line when using code completion for Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide

I'm learning Ruby-on-Rails by following Michael Hartl's [free tutorial.](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning)
The tutorial uses the Cloud9 hosting service and online IDE, which seems to have all of the features I need. However, I'm having a problem with the Intellisense like code completion. When selecting the completion option with either the 'return' or 'tab' keys, the IDE sometimes adds a carriage return and positions the cursor on the line below. Instead, I want it to simply complete the selected item, and position the cursor at the end.

Here is how to reproduce the issue:

1. Login/setup a [Cloud9](https://ide.c9.io) IDE.
2. Create a new, empty ruby project. Install rails if needed via `gem install rails -v 4.2.2` (the version is irrelevant)
3. Change to the work-space directory with `cd ~/workspace` and create the rails framework with `rails _4.2.2_ new [some_app]`
4. Create a new method in the ApplicationController class, located at app/controllers/application_controller.rb with an arbitrary definition. For example:

   `def test
       render text: "Blah"
     end`
5. Edit the routes.rb file (or any file for that matter), un-comment the root line and change it to `root 'application#test'`. Notice the auto-completion. If you type "app" the auto completion brings up "application". Good, now you can press tab and have "application" auto-typed, with the cursor after 'n'. Now type "#t" and the auto-completion will come up with "test". Again, good. However, this time if you press tab to select "test" the IDE completes the function name, adds a return, and positions the cursor and the closing ' on the next line.

This is not an isolated example. I'm not very familiar with either the IDE or the Rails language, but from playing around with various commands and auto-completing them, I've gotten this behavior quite a few times. I can't tell what is causing it, or the reason why some commands are treated differently (adding a carriage return). I also can't find any auto-complete settings inside the IDE.

I like auto-complete, and while this isn't a deal breaker, it does make auto-complete almost useless as it takes much more time to notice the extra line, erase it, and continue on then it does to just complete the word myself.

Please no suggestions on how I shouldn't use auto-complete when learning a language or similar advice.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed guide, I followed it and reproduced it easily. I've logged an internal issue on this. If you'd like, I can keep you updated here or you can email support@c9.io and I can keep you updated via email.

Comment: @BradyDowling this is still happening.. Any update?